# Passing text field value to Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm fairly new to Rails and I'm stuck with passing a text field value to Rails Controller method. Any help is appreciated, below is my code..

View code:

Upon click of the below button I want to be able to send the username to the Controller method..

```
<%= link_to "My button", admin_user_creds_path(user_config),
        method: :test_user, role: "button" %>
```

The username is entered in a text field:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, user_config] do |f| %>
  <td class="js-editable-text rf-table__td rf-table__col--username">
  <div class="preview js-preview show"><%= user_config.username %></div>
  <div class="js-input hide"><%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control" %></div>
</td>
```

My routes file:

```
post "/user_configurations/:id", to: "user_configurations#test_user", as: "user_creds"
```

My controller:

```
def test_user
  username = user_params[:username]
end
def user_params
  params.require(:user_configurations).permit(:username)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `link_to` helper you need add a submit button to your form.

```
<%= form_for [:admin, user_config] do |f| %>
  <td class="js-editable-text rf-table__td rf-table__col--username">
  <div class="preview js-preview show"><%= user_config.username %></div>
  <div class="js-input hide"><%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control" %></div>
  <%= f.submit "My button" %>
</td>
```

Also please note that `method` option in `link_to` helper is either `get` or `post` HTTP methods but not the controller action

Comment: Thanks for your response! The problem is that there is another button on this page and this button's controller method gets called when I change that to f.submit.
    <%= f.button  "Update" %> is the other button on the page

Comment: Probably you need to change declaration:
`form_for [:admin, user_config]` to `form_for url: user_creds_path`